# Extract EF Core DbContextOptions from DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, ef-core-5.0

After a `DbContext` is created, is it possible to extract the  `DbContextOptions` that was used to create it?

(Perhaps by using something similar to [`RelationalOptionsExtension.Extract()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.relationaloptionsextension?view=efcore-5.0), an EF infrastructure service, etc.)

Comment: I need this during testing

Comment: DbContext.Database has many of the configured options

Comment: @ErikEJ Thanks, yes had a look there. Unfortunately it's the actual options object that I'm looking for. I was looking in the various internal namespaces for something "unsupported" but couldn't find anything there either. I guess it's hidden once the context is instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No official (public) way. But you can use two (internal) infrastructure methods to obtain it.

First is the [`GetService<TService>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.accessorextensions.getservice?view=efcore-5.0) extension method located in [`AccessorExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.accessorextensions?view=efcore-5.0) class, which then can be used to obtain the `IDbContextServices` service instance - undocumented, but one of its members is

```cs
IDbContextOptions ContextOptions { get; }
```

which is exactly what you need.

So the code is like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;

DbContext dbContext;
var dbOptions = db.GetService<IDbContextServices>().ContextOptions;
```

Note that the return type is interface, but it can be cast to `DbContextOptions` if needed.

Comment: I don't use internal namespaces in production code - but this is for a unit test, so I don't mind. Thanks for this very nice workaround. Your expert knowledge of EF internals continues to amaze me! :)

Answer (score 1):

What I use is a factory method that can return either a `DbContext` or a `DbContextOptions` object. Afterwards I use that either in DI (Autofac) or for unitests (usually an in-memory db).

If this isn't an option you could probably use Reflection and create an extension method to return the private field `private readonly DbContextOptions _options;` from the DbContext object. This is kind of a hack and workaround, if you control the instantiation of the DbContext I would use option one.

Comment: Using reflection could be troublesome as the field could change somehow between major versions - but in a unit test it's a reasonable option. Thanks for this nice idea!

Answer (score 0):

[OnConfiguring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.onconfiguring?view=efcore-5.0) is run for each DbContext instance so you can override it to examine and modify DbContextOptionsBuilder passed in.

Comment: Thanks. I can get the builder in that method and the options from the builder, but my goal is to get the options once the context already exists. In a testing environment that would be very useful to me. Your answer is of course the proper way to do it in all other cases.

Comment: Point it you can stash it away somewhere where you can examine it later.  And you can do this _only_ in testing if you want by introducing a new DbContext subtype.

Comment: Yeah that's a nice workaround, but in my case that would too require a redesign. If I find no way to extract the options from a live context, I'll redesign to do something like you proposed.